# Which of these two DB design approaches is better?

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship

I have following entities, EntityA, EntityB, EntityC and EntityD:

```
+----------+    +----------+    +----------+    +----------+
|  EntityA |    |  EntityB |    |  EntityC |    |  EntityD |
+----------+    +----------+    +----------+    +----------+
|  FC1     |    |  FC1     |    |  FC1     |    |  FC1     |
|  FC2     |    |  FC2     |    |  FC2     |    |  FC2     |
|  FC3     |    |  FC3     |    |  FC3     |    |  FC3     |
|  FC4     |    |  FC4     |    |  FC4     |    |  FC4     |
|  EA1     |    |  EB1     |    |  EC1     |    |  ED1     |
|  EA2     |    |  EB2     |    |  EC2     |    |  ED2     |
|  EA3     |    |          |    |  EC3     |    |  ED3     |
|  EA4     |    |          |    |          |    |  ED4     |
+----------+    +----------+    +----------+    +----------+
```

Each entity has properties FC1, FC2, FC3 and FC4 that are common across all the entities; and some properties are specific to the entity. Also each entity references every other entity in the domain. There is a many-to-many relation between entities.

Which of the following DB designs is better? Or is there any other better approach than the two described below?

1)

```
                              +-------------+
                              |    Link     |
                              +-------------+
                          +---|  id_T1(FK)  |
                          +---|  id_T2(FK)  |
    +---------------+     |   +-------------+
    |  TableCommon  |     |
    +---------------+     |
+-->|  id(PK)       |<----+-------+------------------+------------------+
|   |  FC1          |             |                  |                  |
|   |  FC2          |             |                  |                  |
|   |  FC3          |             |                  |                  |
|   |  FC4          |             |                  |                  |
|   +---------------+             |                  |                  |
|                                 |                  |                  |
|   +----------+    +----------+  |    +----------+  |    +----------+  |
|   |  TableA  |    |  TableB  |  |    |  TableC  |  |    |  TableD  |  |
|   +----------+    +----------+  |    +----------+  |    +----------+  |
+---|  id(FK)  |    |  id(FK)  |--+    |  id(FK)  |--+    |  id(FK)  |--+
    |  EA1     |    |  EB1     |       |  EC1     |       |  ED1     |
    |  EA2     |    |  EB2     |       |  EC2     |       |  ED2     |
    |  EA3     |    |          |       |  EC3     |       |  ED3     |
    |  EA4     |    |          |       |          |       |  ED4     |
    +----------+    +----------+       +----------+       +----------+
```

In this design, the common properties of the entities above are stored in a separate table, the TableCommon; this table can be thought as the base table from which every other tables are derived. The Link table above stores the reference of one entity to other entity in the domain representing many-to-many relationship between entities.

2)

```
+----------+          +----------+    +----------+    +----------+
|  TableA  |          |  TableB  |    |  TableC  |    |  TableD  |
+----------+          +----------+    +----------+    +----------+
|  id(PK)  |<--+  +-->|  id(PK)  |    |  id(PK)  |    |  id(PK)  |
|  FC1     |   |  |   |  FC1     |    |  FC1     |    |  FC1     |
|  FC2     |   |  |   |  FC2     |    |  FC2     |    |  FC2     |
|  FC3     |   |  |   |  FC3     |    |  FC3     |    |  FC3     |
|  FC4     |   |  |   |  FC4     |    |  FC4     |    |  FC4     |
|  EA1     |   |  |   |  EB1     |    |  EC1     |    |  ED1     |
|  EA2     |   |  |   |  EB2     |    |  EC2     |    |  ED2     |
|  EA3     |   |  |   |          |    |  EC3     |    |  ED3     |
|  EA4     |   |  |   |          |    |          |    |  ED4     |
+----------+   |  |   +----------+    +----------+    +----------+
               |  |
+----------+   |  |   +----------+    +----------+    +----------+
| TableAB  |   |  |   | TableAC  |    | TableAD  |    | TableBC  |
+----------+   |  |   +----------+    +----------+    +----------+
| id_1(FK) |---+  |   | id_1(FK) |    | id_1(FK) |    | id_1(FK) |  ...
| id_2(FK) |------+   | id_2(FK) |    | id_2(FK) |    | id_2(FK) |
+----------+          +----------+    +----------+    +----------+
```

In this design each entity is represented by it's own table. The common properties of the entities are not extracted into a separate table. But separate tables are created to represent many-to-many relations between each entity e.g. TableAB represents link between TableA and TableB, similarly TableBC represents link between TableB and TableC and so on. In this case there will be total 6 tables, TableAB, TableAC, TableAD, TableBC, TableBD and TableCD representing many-to-many relations between all the 4 entity tables, TableA, TableB, TableC and TableD.

From the above two designs I can think of following pros and cons for each:

First design:

Pros:

1. There are less tables created in the design.
2. Any change in the common properties of the entities has to be made in only one table, the TableCommon.
3. Adding new entity in the design is easy.

Cons:

1. All the addition, update and deletion has to be made through a single table, the TableCommon, to maintain referential integrity. That could be a bottleneck.
2. Adding entries into an entity table has to be done in two tables.

Second Design:

Pros:

1. Each entity is represented by a separate table hence there is no bottleneck while addition, update and deletion.
2. Adding entries in an entity table has to be done in a single table.

Cons:

1. Too many tables are created for storing references between entities.
2. Adding new entity is cumbersome.
3. Changing common properties of entities has to be done in all the entity tables.

Which of the above designs is better, or is there some other even better approach? Here better is in terms of performance, storage space, maintainance and scalability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you answered many part of your question very well. I just notify some other points.

**Note 1**: about `TableCommon` strategy

I strongly recommend to use `TableCommon` to save common fields. It has not many side effects on your evaluation parameters (Performance, Redundancy, Scalability, Maintenance and etc.).

**Note 2**: about `Link` table strategy
The parameters that are important here:

1. The number of records in Entities A,B,C and D
2. The number of record in many-to-many relationships among them
3. The number of CRUDs from these many-to-many relationships

If you have **a lot of** records in them and you have **a lot of** CRUDs and the performance of them is vital, you **should not** use `Link` table strategy.

However, If you have **only** two or more tables (for example `EntityA` and `EntityB`) that have a lot of records in many-to-many relationship, you can use `EntityAB` strategy **only** for them and use `Link` table strategy for the others.

**Note 3**: using Fact Table between Entity A,B,C and D

I know that it is **very bad design** at the first look. 
But, based on the evaluation parameters, it can be **useful** in **some cases**.

Using Fact Table like this:
gathering F.Ks of all Entities A,B,C and D in one table.

**First** Cons:

1. If the many-to-many relationships have many other fields, we **cannot** use this strategy.
2. There are many bad **Nullification** in that Fact Table.

Pros:

1. You can fetch all `EntityA` relationships in one record.
2. Reduce the number of entities.
3. Reduce the number of records.

Comment: Your question may have an answer   [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/193394/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-have-several-mutually-exclusive-one-to-one-relationships/193401#193401)

Comment: @WalterMitty, Thanks a lot, I am familiar with Inheritance mapping techniques. I am trying to provide a solution for **a lot of many-to-many relationships** in the question (with Note 2 and Note 3).